# Java how to generate and assign attributes to an Object in an efficient way?

Tags: java, automation

I'm building an automation testing program, I'd like it to have ability to generator fake customer data. To do that, I've done things like:
- Created a Customer Object which has 40 variables
- Created a GustGenerator Class to generate faker data and assign to Customer object.

```
//Customer object class
public class Customer {

        public static final String EMAIL = "user.name@******.com";
        public static final String PHONE = "0956***2001";
        public static final String LAS_NAME = "Owen";
        public static final String FIN_PURP_TYPE = "ELP";
        public static final String ADDRESS = "User Address";
        private String title;
        private String firName;
        private String midName;
        private boolean isReqMet;
        private int media;
        ...... 40 attributes in total.
        ...... getters and setters
}

//Fake customer data generator.
public class CustGenerator {

    private Customer customer;
    private Faker faker = new Faker();

    private Customer firstName(Customer customer) {
        customer.setFirName(faker.name().firstName());
        return customer;
    }

    private Customer midName(Customer customer) {
        customer.setMidName(faker.name().lastName());
        return customer;
    }

    ......Generate data one by one.
}
```

My question is is there a better way to construct this feature? More simple and more efficiency. Any input is appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by creating a constructer function in your customer class:-

```
Public class Customer{

...create variables

Public Customer(bool random){
    If(random){
        //generate variables randomly
    }else{
        //initiallize what do you want
    }
}

}
```

And also i suggest if parameters is such more create a dictionary instead of creating a lot of variables, for e.g:-

```
Dictionary<string, object> vals = new Dictionary<string, object>();
```

And if you just use string values so make second parameter  to string.

Comment: Thanks @Azhy, the first suggestion is great. About Dictionary, may I know why you think dictionary is better than object?

Comment: Because creating 40 variables is some strange or is hard, one dict can does what they do easily using key and values.